# Validate textbox with RegularExpressionValidator

Tags: asp.net

I have a text box that I want to validate the format of text: P-xxxxxxxx-xxxxx-xx.
I need that "xxxxxxxx" to be stricted 8 digit, "xxxxx" to be from 1 to 5 digit and also "xx" to be 1 or 2 digit.
How can I do it with regular expression validator
My textbox is in asp.net :

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="CadastralNumberTextBox" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" meta:resourcekey="CadastralNumberTextBoxResource1"
                                            Text='<%# Bind("CadastralNumber") %>' Width="98%" ReadOnly="false"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: unclear what exactly do you want

Comment: I want the user in that textbox to write just the format I will give in the regularexpression validator. and the format should be P-xxxxxxxx(8 digits)-xxxxx(1 or 5 digits)-xx(1 or 2 digits). Is that clear. I am asking how can I do this with regular expression validator

Comment: still not clear, if you have any link or some information other than this that would be great

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression to validate P-XXXXXXXX-XXXXX(1 **or** 5 digits)-XX(1 or 2 digits) you would use `([P]-\d{8}-(\d{1}|\d{5})-(\d{1,2}))` as your regular expression.

To validate P-XXXXXXXX-XXXXX(1 **to** 5 digits)-XX(1 or 2 digits), you would use `([P]-\d{8}-(\d{1,5})-(\d{1,2}))` as your validator

The first one requires the second grouping of numbers to be exactly 1 or 5 digits long, whereas the second one requires the second grouping of numbers to be 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5 digits longs.

I hope this answers your question.

Edit: http://www.regexr.com/ is a really useful site for this kind of issue. It has helpful information on syntax and will live match your regex, so you can test it.